# Codeigniter custom URL structure

Tags: codeigniter, url

I want Url in my codeigniter app like this,

```
in Home www.domain.com/ -> i route the $config defaut_controller to category

in page 2, www.domain.com/category/[category_name]/    -> in here (page 2) i create pagination.

in page 3, www.domain.com/category/[categori_name]/[sub_category1_name]   ->in here i create pagination too.

and then, in page 4 i want www.domain.com/category/[categori_name]/[sub_category1_name]/[sub_category2_name].
```

In my database, I have table category, sub_category1, sub_category2. and string url in every table.

I was try using `_remap($method, $params = array())` function, but i can't do it.
Can anybody give me approch to do this? or reference similar web structure.

Comment: You would simply edit the `routes.php` file.  [Have you read the documentation yet?](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use routes for this.

**In application/config/config.php:**

**For page 1:**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'category';
```

**For page 2:**

```
$route["category/(:any)"] = "category/index/$1";
```

**For page 3:**

```
$route["category/(:any)/(:any)"] = "category/index/$1/$2";
```

**For page 4:**

```
$route["category/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)"] = "category/index/$1/$2/$3";
```

**Side note:**

If you still facing the issue than create seperate function in category controller for sub_category and change index to function name in controller.